# Defining new unit commands as derivatives of `\si` units

Tags: siunitx

In my document, I need to use a large number of different SI units. To ease my typing, I usually define new commands as `\newcommand{\unitmass}{\si{\kilogram}}` or `\newcommand{\unitmomentum}{\si{\kilogram\meter\per\second}}`. Then I can use something like `2.5\unitmass`or `3.4\unitmementum` and be done. It saves me a lot of typing effort.

Not much of a problem till I need `\si[2.5d-15]{\kilogram\meter\per\second}` (notice the scientific notation of the number), which still requires me to type the full shebang. One alternative is to use math notation only for the number as in `$2.5\times 10^{-17}$\unitmomentum$` which is not a terrific option. Ideally I would want something like `\unitmomentum[2.5d-15]` to get by.

Which means, I have to define my commands way more complicated and there are dozens (rapidly reaching hundred) of it. Hence I must define a template of optional argument accepting commands.

My first approach was to

```
\newcommand{\SimpleSIunit}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\si{#2}}%
}
```

It works if I remain content with no optional arguments. I can issue dozens of directives like `\SimpleSIunit{unittorque}{\newton\meter}` and my basic need is met.

However, what I really want is to say

```
\newcommand{\SimpleSIunit}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand[1][]\csname #1\endcsname{\si[##1]{#2}}%
}
```

Which obviously does no good. Any ideas how do I rectify it?

After I pronounce `\SimpleSIunit{unittorque}{\newton\meter}`, I want these four lines to produce the same output -

```
2.5\unittorque
\unittorque[2.5]
2.5\si{\newton\meter}
\si[2.5]{\newton\meter}
```

** PS:: EDIT after comment  by @daleif **

The spacings are taken care of by the following directives before I do anything else. It uses the `savesym` package. I don't pretend that the code below is my original work. Call it Cargo-cult programming, but I am no student in need of a homework. This is my professional work and I use LaTeX as a tool.

```
% spacing of siunits
\newlength{\siunitspace}
\sisetup{number-unit-product = \hspace{\siunitspace}}

% new units -- to act as supplement to SI units package \si{unit}
\input{unitdef-v01-2018} % a seperate file maintains this

\savesymbol{si}
\newcommand{\si}[2][?]{%
    \if\relax#1\relax%
    \hspace{\siunitspace}\origsi{#2}\xspace%
    \else%
    \if?#1\hspace{\siunitspace}\origsi{#2}\xspace\else\SI{#1}{#2}\xspace\fi%
    \fi%
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `2.5\si...` is wrong? The inner value spacing is missing. You do not really gain anything by doing this compared to just using `\SI`

Comment: I am sorry, I had already changed those spacings. I am editing my question, though it doesn't change anything as far as the original problem is i.e, defining templatized commands to accept optional arguments.

Comment: Why not use \num{2.5d-15}\unitmomentum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is functionality built in to `siunitx` for this type of input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{free-standing-units, ,unit-optional-argument, space-before-unit}
\DeclareSIUnit{\unitmomentum}{\kilogram\meter\per\second}
\begin{document}
Some text $3.5\unitmomentum$ and $\unitmomentum[2.5e-3]$.
\end{document}
```

Note that this `units`-like syntax is not the default setting as I believe that it is sub-optimal.

Comment: hmmm ... it works. thanks a lot. I found that using `use-xspace` solves the problem of lack of space after the units.